# Calling a Matrix from one class to other / main

Tags: c++, matrix

I am new to C++, and developing a power system simulation algorithm for my own project....

So far I got very good results for the load flow algorithm.
I am trying to optimize the calculation by creating many classes.

However, for each variable `xxx`, (int, doubles, array/vector) I was able to call it outside the class using `Class.xxx`, except for matrix type (`vector<vector<complex<double>>>`). This is part of the code:

```
class Load_Flow_Class {
public:

    vector<vector<complex<double>>> Ybus; // this is a complexe matrix

    vector<complex<double>> LPQIK; 
    vector<complex<double>> LPQKI; 
    complex<double> TotalLineLoses;
    int slackbus;

//....... initiate matrix and calculate values.....................

    void YBIKmatrix (int nbus) {
        vector<vector<complex<double>>> Ybus(nbus);

        for (int i = 0; i < nbus; i++) {
            Ybus[i].resize(nbus);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nbus; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nbus; j++) {
                Ybus[i][j]=/*.....*/
            }
        }
    }

cout << LF.Ybus[i][j]; //-------------> no issue

//.................from main()......................

nbus = 5; //example

Load_Flow_Class LF;
LF.YBIKmatrix(nbus);

for (int i /*....*/) {
    for (int j /*....*/) {
        cout << LF.Ybus[i][j];
        //----> no display and cause the program to stop 
    }
}
```

This only happens with the matrix type (`Ybus`)

Answer (score 1):

While I was editing your question to make it clearer, I noticed two lines in particular. This line in the class definition:

```
vector<vector<complex<double>>> Ybus; // this is a complexe matrix
```

And this line in the `YBIKmatrix` method:

```
vector<vector<complex<double>>> Ybus(nbus);
```

Because you declared the variable again in the member function, it *shadows* the class member `Ybus`. All changes that happen to `Ybus` in the function only happen to the local variable, not the class variable.

To remedy this, remove this line in the member function:

```
vector<vector<complex<double>>> Ybus(nbus);
```

If you do want to set the size of the vector, you can use `resize` instead, rather than attempting to construct it again.

```
Ybus.resize(nbus);
```

Comment: This line is to initialize the size of the matrix. By deleting this line from member function, did that work?

Comment: @HatemTagourti If you want to initialise the size of the matrix, you can use the `resize` function as you do in the loop. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: I deleted the line for matrix initialization, and it didn't work because the complete size is not complete.

Comment: I passed Ybus to YBIKmatrix member function. I am copying the matrix outside the class and returned back to the other member function in the same class...

Comment: it happens only for the matrix, not for another array (vector<double>). I am using the same method for initialization inside the member function without any issue